# this.setState cannot set state inside if condition ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have below validation code for a form in react:

```
validateRegister=()=>{
var flag=false;
        if(this.state.username.length<3)
            {this.setState({...this.state,nameError:'Name must be atleast 3 characters long!'});flag=true;}

        if(this.state.address.length==0)
            {this.setState({...this.state,addressError:'Address cannot be empty!'});flag=true;}

        if(this.state.phone.length!=10)
            {this.setState({...this.state,phoneError:'Phone no should be 10 digits long!'});flag=true;}

        if(this.state.email=='')
            {this.setState({...this.state,emailError:'Email cannot be empty!'});flag=true;}

        if(!this.state.password.length>=8||!this.state.password.length<=12)
            {this.setState({...this.state,passError:'Password should be between 8-12 characters!'});flag=true;}

        setTimeout(()=>{console.log(this.state);},2000);
            return flag;
}
```

What this code does is that it sets the error whenever any field doesn't meet the required criteria. Now the problem is that if I submit the form without filling any field, then what should have been done is that all the errors should have been set. But instead what is happening is that only the password error is set(tha last one), and all other errors are empty. This is conclusive from the `setTimeout` function, where I see only pass error been set.

```
username: ""
password: ""
address: ""
phone: ""
email: ""
passError: "Password should be between 8-12 characters!"
emailError: ""
nameError: ""
phoneError: ""
addressError: ""
redirect: false
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? I am getting absolutely no clue for this.

Thanks!

Comment: This is happening because setting state is an async operation. So because of that it is updating only the last condition.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I think the reason is something else.

Comment: Try to change the order of if conditions and you will see that the condition which is at last  will have the correct values.

Comment: Try to compute all the errors at one time and set the errors, but this can overcome your async operation, if you want to run any function after updating, use `this.setState({...this.state, errors}, yourfunction});`

Comment: I have found the issue. I removed ``this.state`` and everything worked like charm